how to run data processing tasks asynchronously in fast api?
I have a route in my fast api application, (sample code below). my root route calls an async function called read_root. in this function , i want to query database , gets some result and upload it to aws in a s3 bucket. I don't necessarily have to wait for the database operations to finish, as it may take time processing the data and uploading it to s3. I created another async function called call_database do the database call , processing and finally uploading the files to s3, but this operation is all synchronous, i.e calling database , getting results from database and processing data and then uploading to s3.
my question , is can function defined as async process such synchronous operations ? and while those are in process, is it ok to return the response ('hello': 'world') in my case , to the http call . this will end that http request/response. but i am assuming the call_database function will keep running until the files are uploaded to s3?
is this a correct understanding and implementation?
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    await call_database()

    return {"Hello": "World"}


async def call_database():
   //syncrohonous call to database
   //get the result back , and upload it to aws s3


The await behavior in Python blocks the execution of the co-routine (in this case, the read_root function), until the awaitable completes (the call_database function). What this means in practical terms is that your current code won't return your {"Hello": "World"} response until after the database operation is done.

To supersede the execution of those operations (calling the db, uploading the s3), you probably want to use task queues. FastAPI includes support for background tasks. Another recommended approach is using Celery, which is a battle tested library for using task queues in Python.

Related StackOverflow questions: async/await behavior, FastAPI background tasks

@amoralesc - thanks for your insights. I will go through the link you have provided. conceptually i get that await keyword will wait till say a task is finished and then continue rest of the program. so is there a better example , when should we use async/await construct?

The async/await constructs and the asyncio module in general is best used when your program is I/O bound and I think the performance improvements are clearer when there are multiple I/O operations executing concurrently. Hitting a database is precisely an I/O operation (as well as uploading a file to S3, for that matter). Since you are using FastAPI, I'm also guessing you are using an ASGI server like uvicorn + an ORM/query builder that supports async. It is a perfectly valid approach to define your database calls as async functions in this scenario.

Since database operations are something you usually expect to return to your client (be that to return a query, the result of a write operation or a possible error in execution), async/await works best here (as opposed to offloading these to a background executor). But the actual performance improvements over synchronous code can only be seen if you are measuring them. So I recommend you run some benchmarks, sending multiple requests per second to your API and testing it yourself. Also check out FastAPI docs on async.

Now, very slow operations (and by slow I mean >10 secs) that one doesn't usually expect to report the result of to a client immediately (like uploading large files to S3), are best suited to a background executor. This is when FastAPI background tasks or Celery tasks come to shine. You can then choose how to report the result of these operations to your client, depending on your use case: simple db update, email, webhook, etc. Other example of background tasks are scheduled units of work that you need to run every x interval of time, e.g. cleaning up files in the server everyday at midnight.

In addition to the links provided in the banner above, please have a look at this answer and this answer

I think you're looking for background task
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()

def upload_to_s3(data: dict):
    # your upload process here

@app.get("/")
async def read_root(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    data_to_upload = await call_database()
    background_tasks.add_task(upload_to_s3, data_to_upload)
    return {"Hello": "World"}


async def call_database():
   //syncrohonous call to database
   


You're missing the declaration for background_tasks.
